# Why does Rails I18n.t in asset pipline file not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, rails-i18n

I want to use `I18n.t` helper in asset pipeline `js.coffee.erb` file.

My local file:

```
zh-CN:
  hello: 你好
```

In `hello.js.coffee.erb`:

```
$->
  alert '<%= t(:hello) %>'
```

This will cause an `"Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError - "\xE5" on US-ASCII"` error.

Does asset pipeline file support using `I18n.t` helper?

error log:

```
Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError - "\xE5" on US-ASCII
  (in /.../hello.js.coffee.erb):
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:123:in `escape'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:69:in `escape'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:177:in `encode_json'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:220:in `block in encode_json'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:220:in `encode_json'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:48:in `block in encode'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:77:in `check_for_circular_references'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:46:in `encode'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:31:in `encode'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_json.rb:16:in `to_json'
  (gem) multi_json-1.6.1/lib/multi_json/adapters/json_common.rb:10:in `dump'
  (gem) multi_json-1.6.1/lib/multi_json.rb:122:in `dump'
  (gem) execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/json.rb:11:in `encode'
  (gem) execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:33:in `call'
  (gem) coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:57:in `compile'
  (gem) tilt-1.3.5/lib/tilt/coffee.rb:46:in `evaluate'
  (gem) tilt-1.3.5/lib/tilt/template.rb:77:in `render'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:193:in `block in evaluate'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:190:in `evaluate'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:249:in `block in build_asset'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:270:in `circular_call_protection'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:248:in `build_asset'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `block in build_asset'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:111:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `resolve_dependencies'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:97:in `build_required_assets'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:249:in `block in build_asset'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:270:in `circular_call_protection'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:248:in `build_asset'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `block in build_asset'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `build_asset'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `block in build_asset'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/environment.rb:78:in `find_asset'
  (gem) sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:177:in `[]'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:126:in `asset_for'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:27:in `block in javascript_include_tag'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:26:in `javascript_include_tag'
  app/views/layouts/_head.html.slim:19:in `_app_views_layouts__head_html_slim___1053294957777409236_46504920'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:265:in `render_partial'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:238:in `block in render'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:237:in `render'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:41:in `render_partial'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:27:in `render'
  (gem) haml-4.0.0/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:12:in `render_with_haml'
  app/views/layouts/auth.html.slim:4:in `_app_views_layouts_auth_html_slim___1395664120707387056_5138760'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:59:in `render_with_layout'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
  /home/jx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `_run__2781514901838594071__process_action__4110693920995885568__callbacks'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  (gem) journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  (gem) journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
  (gem) meta_request-0.2.2/lib/meta_request/middlewares/app_request_handler.rb:11:in `call'
  (gem) rack-contrib-1.1.0/lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:17:in `call'
  (gem) meta_request-0.2.2/lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:16:in `call'
  (gem) meta_request-0.2.2/lib/meta_request/middlewares/meta_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
  (gem) mongoid-3.1.2/lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:34:in `block in call'
  (gem) mongoid-3.1.2/lib/mongoid/unit_of_work.rb:39:in `unit_of_work'
  (gem) mongoid-3.1.2/lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:34:in `call'
  (gem) warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  (gem) warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  (gem) rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1915631577033867377__call__2170704697511918287__callbacks'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  (gem) better_errors-0.7.2/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  (gem) better_errors-0.7.2/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  (gem) better_errors-0.7.2/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  (gem) railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  (gem) railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  (gem) railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  (gem) railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  (gem) railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  (gem) railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  (gem) thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
  (gem) thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
  (gem) thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
  (gem) thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  (gem) eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  (gem) thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
  (gem) thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
  (gem) rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
  (gem) rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
  (gem) railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
  (gem) railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
  (gem) railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
  script/rails:6:in `<main>'
  script/rails:0:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, make sure your `zh-CN.yml` is encoded in **UTF-8**, it looks like it's encoded in **US-ASCII**.

## I18n.js

You can use the `i18n-js` gem to add Javascript internationalization to the Rails asset pipeline (see https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js).

The `i18n-js` gem automatically converts the translations in the `config/locales/` directory to javascript. After you add this gem, call `I18n.t` directly in your javascript (without the `<%=` and `%>`). Translations are stored in javascript and can be viewed at `http://localhost:3000/assets/i18n/translations.js`.

Note that the i18n-js may not completely load between requests, so you may still get `TranslationMissing` errors from time to time, but these should go away when you compile your assets. If this happens during development, try reloading the page.

### Use

1. Add `gem 'i18n-js'` to your `Gemfile`.
2. Run `bundle install`.
3. Add a `zh-CN.yml` file to `config/locals/` with:

   ```
   zh-CN:
     hello: 你好
   ```
4. In `application.js`, add the i18n libraries before `//= require_tree .` and set your default locale (make sure you keep the blank line):

   ```
   //= require i18n
   //= require i18n/translations
   //= require_tree .

   I18n.defaultLocale = "zh-CN";
   ```
5. Once that's done, your `hello.js.coffee.erb` file should look like this:

   ```
   $ ->
     alert I18n.t('hello')
   ```

You should then get the proper internationalized alert when you visit the page.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explain! i18n-js is very useful.

Comment: I applied this, but I now have only the default locale in javascript. How do I tell javascript to get the locale that is set in the url = `?locale=en` for example ?

Comment: Parsing it from the queryString is necessary, then it can be set via `I18n.locale = "pt-BR";`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript for how to parse the queryString.